# Overriding default SdkClientOption.SCHEDULED_EXECUTOR_SERVICE in AWS SDK for Java 2

Tags: aws-java-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0, aws-java-sdk-2.x, aws-sdk-java, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb

Is there a way I can override the default `SdkClientOption.SCHEDULED_EXECUTOR_SERVICE` in AWS SDK for Java 2? I want to get rid of all the threadpools that are opaque to the application, and ensure that the threadpools are reused across all non-blocking contexts.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this. If you work with different services across different AWS accounts and different AWS regions you end up having the SDK create a staggering amount of ThreadPoolExecutors for you and thus a staggering amount of threads.

Comment: See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1690